# Automatically generating variables in AngularJS with specific names

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("workPlan").controller("genericFilterDataController",    ["$scope", genericFilterDataController]);

    function genericFilterDataController($scope) {

        $scope.data = ['bla1', 'bla2', 'bla3'];

        $scope.foo = function () {

             };
        }
    })();
```

When function `foo` is fired I want to generate properties in `$scope` with names listed in the `data` array.

For example:

In function `foo` I want to create properties with names according to the strings in the `data` array:

```
$scope.bla1
$scope.bla2
$scope.bla3
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your 'foo' function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $scope[data[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this -

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular.module("workPlan").controller("genericFilterDataController",    ["$scope", genericFilterDataController]);

 function genericFilterDataController($scope) {

    $scope.data = ['bla1', 'bla2', 'bla3'];

      $scope.foo = function () 
      {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++)
        {
           $scope[$scope.data[i]] = $scope.data[i];// or your data point here
         }

      };
    }
})();
```